# Help understanding Egyptian circle

Tags: geometry, math-history

I was reading this [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Egyptian_geometry) searching for the Egyptian area of circle and there is a following picture there:

[image]

Trying to understand what is meant by this since it is under the "Area" section. I've read some other pieces regarding area of circle where Egyptians usually inscribed the circle inside of a square instead of drawing it like this. There is not much description on the page regarding this picture so just trying to make sense of it. Anyone have any idea what the picture is trying to explain?

Comment: So far as the big circle-square aspect of the image is concerned, it seems to be simply observing that a circle of radius $191$ has approximately the same area as a square of half-width $168$. (That is, $168/191\approx \sqrt{\pi}/2$.)

Comment: @Blue there should be some connection with the things on the right where heights of the curve from the x-axis are measured.

Comment: *"there should be some connection with the things on the right"* Probably ... possibly ... could be. Frankly, I find much of the labeling confusing. ... In any case, I wonder if the dedicated [History of Science and Mathematics SE](https://hsm.stackexchange.com) might have some insights.

Comment: This paper should be useful: https://www.academia.edu/34351812/Ostrakon_of_Saqqara_and_the_formula_of_the_circle